# HTML DIV contradicting a DIV that it is in

Tags: html, css

For the navigation on a website I am making I am using a side bar that is set up using an unordered list. There are also multiple lists inside of lists. I used  multiple div's too. I have now run into the issue that form inside of a div I need to set up some code that will contradict the div that it is in. In my case I have css of line-height: 35px;  I need to edit this to become 15px.

Here is the code i need to edit it is the center( sub List )

```
<li>
  <h2> Tech Ed. Classes</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebarLinks"><!-- USE THIS DIV SECTION FOR A LIST WITH BULLET POINTS -->
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html"><strong><em>Main Page</em></strong></a></li>
       <li><a href="construction.html">Construction</a></li>
       <li><a href="drafting.html">Drafting</a></li>
       <li><a href="electronics.html">Electronics</a></li>
    <ul id="subList">
       <li ><a href="#">INTRODUCTION TO ELECTRONICS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">EXPLORING CAREERS IN ELECTRONICS</a></li>
   </ul>
       <li><a href="graphic.html">Graphic arts </a></li>
       <li><a href="Manufacturing.html">Manufacturing</a></li>
       <li><a href="project.html">Project Lead the Way</a></li>
       <li><a href="transport.html">Transportation, Distribution, & Logitstics</a></li>
       <li><a href="woodworking.html">Wood Working</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to do?

Comment: can you make an example on jsfiddle.com , put enough CSS and HTML to give an example of what you have so far

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by adding a css class to the elements you want to change to be different from the div they are in. For example:

```
li {
    line-height: 35px;
}

.smaller {
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

This CSS will make the line-height on all `<li>` elements equal to 35px, except for `<li>` elements with a class of `smaller`. Those will have a line-height of 15px. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>This will have a line height of 35 pixels.</li>
    <li class="smaller">This will have a height of 15 pixels.</li>
</ul>
<ul class="smaller">
    <li>This will have a line height of 15 pixels, the ul has a class of smaller.</li>
    <li class="smaller">This will have a height of 15 pixels as well.</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6KDZG/1/)

Comment: Good, I'm glad :) Would you please accept this answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a more specific selector for the inner list. This method would not require any changes to your existing markup:

```
#sidebarLinks {
    line-height: 25px;
}
#sidebarLinks #subList {
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the above selectors: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chicgeek/Q76Wn/)